# Wordpress plugin form submitting

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a plugin for saving the reply me details. But whenever I submit the form using the plugin, it shows an error and it is redirected to some other page that shows 'Not Found
Apologies, but the page you requested could not be found. Perhaps searching will help." message. Please check my code

```
<?PHP
/*
Plugin Name: Register Me
Plugin URI: http://demo.net
Description: Plugin is shows a simple Registration form
Author: Sumod Nair
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://demo.net
*/
add_action('init', 'reg_install');
function reg_install()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix."reg_details";
    $structure = "CREATE TABLE $table (
        id INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
        place VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        mobno VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        about_me VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
        date_apply datetime,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";
    $wpdb->query($structure);
}

add_shortcode('register', 'process_post');

function process_post(){
//include("reg_form.php");
?>
<form id="frmRegistration" name="frmRegistration" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">
<table style="align:center; width:500px; margin: 0 0 0 0;"> 
<tr>
<td>Name </td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="50" ><b><font color="red">*</font></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Place </td>
<td><input type="text" name="place" id="place" maxlength="50" ><b><font color="red">*</font></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email </td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="50" ><b><font color="red">*</font></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile No</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" maxlength="50"><b><font color="red">*</font></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>About Yourself</td>
<td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="about" id="about" >

</textarea> <b><font color="red">*</font></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit Details" style="color:blue;"></td>
 <td align="right"><b><font color="red">*</font></b> fileds are mandatory</td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?PHP
   global $wpdb;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix."reg_details";
 if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
   // process $_POST data here
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $place = $_POST['place'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];

   $mobile_no = $_POST['mobile_no'];
   $about_yourself = $_POST['about'];
   echo $name." " .$place." " .$email ." " .$mobile_no." " .$about_yourself;
  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table(name, place,email,mobno,about_me,date_apply)
        VALUES('$name', '$place',' $email', '$mobile_no', '$about_yourself',now())");
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you view the generated HTML of your form, what does `<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>` come out as?

Comment: You will want to check the value generated in your form's action attribute.
    action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>"

It appears that your form is posting to a page that doesn't exist.

You can also change the action attribute to post to itself by setting `action="#"`

Comment: Now I tried with #, but still I am getting the same error message. I have removed the action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" from the script. now i am using action="#" but no use.

Comment: If we use "<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" in the script we will get something like rootfolder_wp/wordpress/?page_id=114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `name="name"` with something else, I've ran into exactly the same "bug". To be sure, also replace other names with some unique string before it. E.g. `name="frm-name"`, `name="frm-mobile_no"`, etc.